# highslide.js - how to hide image filename

Tags: javascript, css, highslide

I have phpBB forum installed, and recently I installed highslide image viewer for phpBB. The problem is that when an image doesn't have an alt text then in stead image filename is displayed when the image is clicked (enlarged).

To be more specific, it looks like this:

[image]

So, any ideas how can I get rid of it?

Comment: @CBroe this is an existing forum with tons of images, and people post images all the time, so this was not a solution at all. :) I need to get rid of that line.

Comment: Well then look at the template where this output is generated, and remove it there.

Comment: Agreed. The Highslide JS script, on its own, does not do this. It must be buried in the phpBB plugin somewhere. I suspect the plugin is using http://highslide.com/ref/hs.captionEval, and automatically selecting the filename if there is no alt attribute.